# How to set a css style to the last item of CListView?

Tags: php, html, css, yii

I want to apply a different style for last entity of CListView , I noticed that there is a property "lastItemCssClass" for CMenu but this property does not exist for CListView. Someone would have an idea how to do this?

```
<?php
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        'itemsTagName'=>'ul',
        'summaryText' => '',
        'enablePagination'=>false,
        'itemView'=>'_viewItem',
    ));
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without having more HTML and CSS available you may want to consider the [last-child pseudo selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3alast-child), refined around whatever your PHP's output HTML is.